# Why is the amount of used memory increasing?

Tags: c#, memory

```
private void Draw(){
     int width  = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
     int height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
     Bitmap image= new Bitmap(width, height);
     Graphics gr =  Graphics.FromImage(image);
     gr.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(width, height));
     Random rnd = new Random();

     gr.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Red, rnd.Next(100)), rnd.Next(300), rnd.Next(100), rnd.Next(600), rnd.Next(1000));
     Point[] p = new Point[3];
     p[0] = new Point(rnd.Next(30),  rnd.Next(60));
     p[1] = new Point(rnd.Next(100), rnd.Next(260));
     p[2] = new Point(rnd.Next(30),  rnd.Next(10));
     gr.DrawPolygon(Pens.AliceBlue, p);
     gr.DrawBeziers(Pens.Yellow, p);
     pcImageBox.Image = image;
}
```

When I use `Timer` and call the `Draw()` method every 300 milliseconds everything works fine, but when I look into process manager, my project uses more memory (memory increases every 300 milliseconds)

Maybe I should use garbage collector or use `p = null;` etc. How can I resolve this problem?

Thank you for help and sorry for my bad english..

Comment: Side note: you are creating local Random generator instead of using shared one. It is OK in this case (since calls to Draw are separated by more than 10-20ms) but check your other code for similar creation of Random inside frequently called method...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never disposed your `Graphics` object.

Use `using`, like:

```
using (Graphics gr =  Graphics.FromImage(image)) {
     ...
}
pcImageBox.Image = image;
```

Also, don't create a brand new `Bitmap` every frame.  Save the old one in a member variable, and draw over it during the next call.  Only make a new one if the screen size changes (`Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds != image.Size`).

Comment: @mellamokb: He should do something to avoid creating a bunch of undisposed `Bitmap` objects, but reusing the previous one is probably better than disposing it while it's attached to a `PictureBox`.

Answer (score 0):

A better method for what you want might be:

[BufferedGraphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bufferedgraphics)